# Rounded corner on JTextField and make it consistent through different PLAFs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, border

Hello dear fellow stackoverflow users,

I got a simple *hack* where I get my long wanted round corners on a `JTextField`.
I found that I could subclass JTextField and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)`

In that regard I could edit the following:

- change the border from standard border to `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()`.
- change the look on the textfield from rectangular to roundrectangular.
- change the offset for the text so it wasn't near the round border. (override `getInsets()`)

Now I'm battling with the following issues:

- Changing the selection size
- When *USER* change the plaf to e.g. Nimbus then the look on the `subclassed JTextField` is ruined, by that I mean Nimbus painting routines is preferred over mine.  So I get a mix of Nimbus and my round borderpainting.

So in very short, does any of you know how I dissect the `JTextField` with the various issues, written above?

Written is my sample code for making rounded borders in a custom class JTextField within the constructor `setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder())` and `setOpaque(false);`:

```
@Override
public Insets getInsets() {
    Insets insets = super.getInsets();
    insets.left += 10;
    return insets;
}

@Override
public Insets getInsets(Insets insets) {
    return insets;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = Graphics2D)g.create();
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
    RoundRectangle2D.Float r2d = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 10, 10);
    Paint backgroundBrush = new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(0x383838), 0, getHeight(), new Color(0xCECECE).darker());
    Shape oldClip = g2.getClip();
    g2.setPaint(backgroundBrush);
    g2.clip(r2d);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
    g2.setClip(oldClip);
    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 10, 10);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
    g2.dispose();
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: Please do *some* proper code formatting! You should be using code tags (```) not >.

Comment: @Ben I welcome you to Stackoverflow; my question is over 10 years old. The tools for format code are horrible, to say the least, but I hope you are happier with this edit.

Comment: better (at least it looks like code now) next step: fix the indentation to make it really readable :)

Answer (score 2):

I would think  you should be creating a custom Border for this. Then you can control the insets and do the painting in the Border, instead of the paintComponent() method of the text field.

Comment: It's [easier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html#custom) than I thought!

Comment: When using a border you cannot control the white background inside the JTextField, atleast not to my knowledge

Comment: @user616693, that is done by using textField.setBackground().

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and found that calling

```
setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))
```

on the text field class cleared it up.  I think that it is not making the background non opaque even if you declare the widget non opaque.